# Websocket connection failed, unexpected response code: 404

Tags: node.js, express, websocket

I have trouble with creating a websocket connection on my express server. I searched a lot on this issue but I just can't find any solution. My code is as follow:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const http = require('http');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const ws = require('ws');

const app = express();

// CORS
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
app.options("*", cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const websocketServer = new ws.Server({ server: httpServer })

websocketServer.on('connection', (websocket, req) => {
  console.log('connected');
})

const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/quizzer`,
    { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true }, () => {
      console.log(`Serverstarted on port ${server.address().port}`);

    });
});
```

The server is started and listening on port 3000. But still I get the following error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

Comment: You should use `httpServer.listen()` instead of `app.listen()` because your express app may have no knowledge about the ws server

Comment: Thanks you very much! This solves the issue.